# Flutter iOS Listview/ScrollView API call issue

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, riverpod

We facing weird issue with Flutter iOS, I have a listview which shows heterogeneous widgets in which some of the widgets are either network images which are rendered using CachedNetworkImage or some have API calls (using Dio) and on success we render widget.

In terms of iOS this widgets with API calls are rendered randomly. They sometimes show up after successful api call and sometimes it just initiates API call and keeps on showing loading widget. Have tried calling API using FutureBuilder but still sometimes gets stuck at loading state.

This issue is not happening on Android and also on debug build of iOS. It can be only be re-produced on iOS release build

Project has riverpod & hooks, were I tried calling API useEffect, FutureProvider, FutureBuilder but all of them have same behaviour.

The expected behavoir is that the listview with this widgets should load consistently same as Android and debug iOS build.

Comment: Please provide some code snippets. Where are your API call executed?